# How to validate Oauth access token in foxx framework

Tags: identityserver4, arangodb, foxx

I am using Identityserver4 for user Authentication. i am not able to find right solution to validate access token at services. (Using Foxx framework to build micro services.)
How can i  Validate IdentityServer(OAUth) access token in foxx framework.

Thanks in advance